# prevent container from jumping

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-float

I'm having a serious brain fart- really an off day. I appreciate the accommodation.

I have two containers, each floated left, and when the window is resized below the width of them, the second container jumps below the first. I'd like it to start overflowing.

dev site at http://dev3.dhut.ch/

seriously, I'm sorry, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap them both in a container div with a width (or min-width) that equals the width of both combined (including any margins or padding).

EDIT: By the look of your example it would appear you just need to put `<header>` inside of `#main`.